# Can the return value for Supplier be incremental

Tags: java, supplier

I am currently dealing with the topics **Consumer** and **Supplier** and have the following question. Can the return value for **Supplier** be incremental?

The following contrived example: I have a simple class **Person** with **id** and **name**. If I need for example for test purposes 10 persons, I want to generate them easily with sequential ids. How can I increment the id when getting it from supplier?

```
class Person {
    long id;
    String name;
}
```

To do something like this is my idea:

```
Supplier<Long> ids      = ()-> 1L;
Supplier<String> names  = ()-> UUID.randomUUID().toString();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Person p = new Person(ids.get(), names.get());
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

Or is the construct **Supplier** not intended for such a use case?

Comment: You mean you want a different value each time you call `get`? You might not be able to use a lambda then.

Comment: Remember that `Supplier` is an `interface`. That means that any class can implement it. For instance, Louis Wasserman used an anonymous class in their example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  You don't have to use a lambda.

```
new Supplier<Long>() {
  long x = 0;
  @Override public Long get() {
    return x++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Didn't know I could do that. Learned something new.

Comment: Or `Supplier<Long> supplier = new AtomicLong()::getAndIncrement`.